# redirect to a url with fragment from a form in an overlay

Tags: forms, uri, modal-dialogs

I'm trying to redirect from a form submit function (form is in an overlay) using either

```
drupal_goto('url',array('fragment'=>'foo'))
```

or

```
$form['redirect'] = array('url',array('fragment'=>'foo'));
```

Both redirect to the url but dont add the frag. Overlay specific issue? Any way around it?

Comment: That should be `$form_state['redirect']`...

Comment: i think it was actually... better double check... shut down dev no this for the week now though. stupid time to ask a questionreally ;-)